# Как переопределить папку .mozilla

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

у меня две версии `firefox` на `ubuntu`
и у них на двоих есть папка `/home/user_name/.mozilla/`
я создал папку `/home/user_name/.mozilla.56/`
как у одного из `firefox` назначить эту папку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сама программа подсказывает:

```
$ firefox --help | grep profile.*path
  --profile <path>   Start with profile at <path>.
```

что надо воспользоваться опцией `--profile путь`:

```
$ firefox --profile путь
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри по этой ссылке [Управление профилями](https://support.mozilla.org/ru/kb/upravlenie-profilyami#w_aiaiikilahulii-laaeika)
Раздел Управление профилями при открытом Firefox или Переименование профиля из под Firefox